# Custom request laravel error

Tags: php, laravel

I have Request:

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    return ['name => 'required'];
}
```

I called this request on controller in methods `store` and `update`. With store method all ok, because method POST. But in method `update` request is PATCH.

When I call method `update`, I get error:

```
Method App\Http\Requests\EsRequest::add does not exist.
```

How I can fix this?

Routes:

```
Route::post('/postadd', 'Post\PostController@store')->name('addpost');
Route::patch('/post/update/{id}', 'Post\PostController@update')->name('editpost');
```

Controller:

```
public function update(EsRequest $request, $id)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    $request->add(['data' => $request->extra]);
    $post->update($request->all());
    return back();
}
```

Comment: copy paste the whole PostController.php file here so we can see it and help you accordingly.

Comment: this is wrong `$request->add(['data' => $request->extra]);`

Comment: I need add to requrest params..

Comment: But it's already there in the request....when you do the dd($request->all()); that extra should be there also...

Comment: In request 2 arrays: data, and extra. I need write to column data dates of the array extra.

Comment: please make a dd($request->all()); and paste it here

Comment: Seems you are calling a wrong route/method: "EsRequest::add" does not match "EsRequest:postadd" from what I can see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$request` supports collections functions. For adding a new parameter you can simply do:

```
$request['data'] = ['foo' => 'bar'];
```

or use collection method as:

```
$request->put('data', ['foo' => 'bar']);
```